# Attaching VHD in Azure Linux VM

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-virtual-machine, disk, vhd

I have a VHD in my storage account. I am able to mount it on my Kubernetes pod. I want to add some files and folders in this disk, so I tried to attach the VHD to one of the VMs in the same resource group. I added it in disk section but I cannot access it when I login to the machine. Please tell me how to mount VHD in my Azure Linux VM or how can I add my data to the VHD any other way.

Comment: the same way you would for any linux vm

Comment: Do you check `fdisk -l` and create file system?